# A question that is an answer to a question nobody asked

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474821/is-possible-to-change-ionics-ion-view-background-color

The user has posted a question *and* answered it himself *within* the question. This is clearly not suitable for the SO Q&A format but what would be the correct close reason for this?

Comment: As far as I know, this is fully ok when done with good intent.

Comment: Should the correct format not be Ask question > provide answer as an answer (not within question body) ? ie. Q&A

Comment: Ah, this is what you mean... Yes, I think you are correct here.

Comment: @Turnip: Yes, that's how the OP should've done it. Self-answered questions are fine, as long as they follow SO's Q/A format and quality guidelines.

Comment: He's done it because he has an answer ban, and now with the meta effect, this will turn into his question ban lynchpin too

Comment: I also see no reason to close. But as OP states in his  question he's banned from providing answers, so someone else should edit out the answer and post that as one.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: He's barely asking a question. "Unclear" applies.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - No, that is not the right approach. Other people might look at that action and repeat the same thing. Editing a bad post into a good one is different from editing a question + answer post into  question and answer posts (when the OP is fully aware that he has been banned from answering questions)

Comment: @TheLostMind OK, I see.

Comment: Why was the question deleted altogether?

Comment: @SajibAcharya: There wasn't a question. It was a answer posted as an question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As commented, self-answered questions are fine, ***provided*** they follow Stack Overflow's Q/A format and quality guidelines.

In this case, a downvote, comment and/or close-vote as "Unclear" should suffice.
I chose "Unclear" as there's hardly a question in there. It's just an answer posted from the "Ask a question" page.

Comment: OK that makes sense. I thought perhaps there was something more specific relating to posts like this. I've come across a couple in the past but couldn't find an example to see how it was handled. Thanks